# Show 2 digits after the decimal point instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python at the moment and I solved some easy coding challenges on hackerrank.com.
But I don't know how to solve this one... The answer is right, but my result is for example 65.0 but hackerrank wants it to be 65.00... How can I add the second decimal number?

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *grades = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, grades))
    student_marks[name] = scores

query_name = input()
average = (student_marks[query_name][0] + student_marks[query_name][1] + student_marks[query_name][2]) / 3

print(average)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using f-strings:

```
value =6.1
print(f'{value:.2f}')
```

Using format:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(value))
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked. I tried the round() method but that didn't work.